# How do I create a systemd service which runs a python script with sudo permissions always that the system starts with a 5s delay?

Tags: systemd, services

I want to create a systemd service which runs a python code some seconds after the startup. I believe I can put this delay in the python script so it's not the important part. I'm just worried about the delay be applied to the system startup itself. The python script must be run with sudo since it will modify some system files.

Comment: Installed systems services run as root. `sudo` is not required.

Comment: Use a monotonic [systemd Timer unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#id-1.7) for such a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your Service By running
`vi /etc/systemd/system/pyhton_script.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=My test Python Script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=root
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/<username>/pyhton_script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable pyhton_script.service --now
systemctl status python_script
```